# Punctuation after beginning of sentence

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

I am wondering about punctuation in this sentence:

> In this case the main focus was on intuitiveness and learnability.

Should I put a comma after "case"? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be called  an **introductory comma**

> We also use commas to link introductory information at the beginning of a sentence. This can be a single word, a phrase (a group of two or more words), or an entire dependent clause. For example:
>
> - “Strangely, he wrote to Michelle but not to me.”
> - “In a way, they are both right.”
> - “When I was traveling in Croatia, I met a lot of interesting people.”

From [**The Free Dictionary - Comma**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Commas.htm)

They then proceed to offer an example where it can be omitted:

> There are some cases in which the introductory element is brief enough or so closely related to the independent clause that the comma is often omitted. The second example, for instance, has an introductory phrase with clear meaning and relation to the sentence, so we could probably leave the comma out, as in:
>
> - “In a way they are both right.”

I prefer the first version - it is less rushed and sounds more natural.